# Using Facebook Graph API, how can i get past events for my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I can see all upcoming events:
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/events?access_token=...

Setting the 'since' parameter to 0 does not show past events.

If anyone has successfully fetched past events through the Graph API please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unfixed bug in the facebook graph API preventing the user from retrieving past events from pages that are not his.

In fact the only solution is to use some FQL like this:

```
SELECT eid, name, description, start_time FROM event WHERE creator = [pageid]
```

Answer (score 0):

The since parameter takes a date as the value in a specific format. For example 2012-08-17T16:20:00-0500. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/dates/ for details on formats.

One thing of note is there seems to be a limit on how far back the API will go in returning the events but I am not sure what this is yet.

Comment: Do you have an example of the API request you are making that is not working?