# facebook graph api returns empty data array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to get the events for a closed group (which has tons of events) via the facebook graph api, but I only got

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) even though I was using an auth token with user_events enabled. Just to be sure, I enabled **every single permission** for the token but got the same result.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/events

Comment: Are you able to get the results with any other closed group? If possible, please provide the group id which have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the answer to my problem; there was nothing wrong!

What I thought were events coming up were actually events that happened in the past, shown in the group/events page; I guess those [aren`t aren't accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054868/using-facebook-graph-api-how-can-i-get-past-events-for-my-page).

I think I'll settle with using FQL as offered as a solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054868/using-facebook-graph-api-how-can-i-get-past-events-for-my-page).